# RxJs Observable completes multiple times

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, reactivex

Below is a short code snippet of reactive code (`RxJs`)

```js
let subj = new Rx.Subject();
let chain = subj
    .switchMap(v => Rx.Observable.of(10*v).do(vv => console.log("Switch map", vv)))
    .share()
    .take(1);


function subscribe(){
  chain.subscribe(v => console.log("Next", v),
                  err => console.log("Error",err),
                  () => console.log("Completed"));
  chain.subscribe(v => console.log("Next2", v),
                  err => console.log("Error2",err),
                  () => console.log("Completed2"));
  subj.next(Math.random());
}

subscribe();
subscribe();
subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

According to the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) `chain` is an `Observable` which should print the emitted value * 10 ([switchMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap)), while printing it only once, no matter what's the number of subscriptions it has ([share](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share)), do it only for the first emitted value and then complete.

The first two bullets work fine, but the last one does not. 
Here is the output I get:

```
Switch map 9.022491050934722
Next 9.022491050934722
Completed
Next2 9.022491050934722
Completed2
Switch map 9.172999425126836
Next 9.172999425126836
Completed
Next2 9.172999425126836
Completed2
Switch map 6.168790337405257
Next 6.168790337405257
Completed
Next2 6.168790337405257
Completed2
```

As you can see, `chain` is getting completed multiple times.
What makes it possible to complete the same `Observable` multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`share` is a shortcut for the combination of `publish` and `refCount`, this means that the stream is only "hot" as long as there is at least 1 subscriber, so after the stream completes, all active subscribers are automatically unsubscribed, which in turn resets the stream, since there are then 0 subscribers. Also: You should put the `take(1)` before the `share` since any following operation affects the hot-state.

How to make the stream *"truely"* shared/hot, independed from any subscribers: Use `publish` and `connect` the stream:

```js
let subj = new Rx.Subject();
let chain = subj
    .switchMap(v => Rx.Observable.of(10*v).do(vv => console.log("Switch map", vv)))
    .take(1)
    .publish();
chain.connect();

function subscribe(){
  chain.subscribe(v => console.log("Next", v),
                  err => console.log("Error",err),
                  () => console.log("Completed"));
  chain.subscribe(v => console.log("Next2", v),
                  err => console.log("Error2",err),
                  () => console.log("Completed2"));
  subj.next(Math.random());
}

subscribe();
subscribe();
subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you're saying that every `Observable` that returns from `share` is being reset and reevaluated upon its completion?

Comment: Not automatically, but as soon as there is a new subscriber.

Comment: Well this explains things. Wish they had it in the documentation. I didn't get the `take` after `share` part. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: It is in the docs: "As long as there is at least one Subscriber this Observable will be subscribed and emitting data. When all subscribers have unsubscribed it will **unsubscribe from the source Observable**" - and of course one of the basic principle in Rx: When you unsubscribe, the stream stops, when you subscribe the stream will start from 0. - Keep in mind, in your example you are **not** completing the Subject, but just you substream - had you completed the `Subject`, then it would behaved more like you had expected it to (though for totally different reasons and not because of the share)

Comment: It does state that "When all subscribers have unsubscribed it will unsubscribe from the source Observable" but it doesn't state that all the subscribers are unsubscribed **automatically** upon stream completion.
Also, didn't know that you can reuse a stream that was already completed by subscribing to it again. Where can I read about it?
Also, could you please elaborate on "*You should put the `take(1)` before the `share` since any following operation affects the hot-state.*"
Thanks!

Comment: That's one of the basic principles, you could probably google for "RxJS intro" - Whenever a stream(ANY stream) completes or throws an error, any subscriber is automatically unsubscribed - as for the order: `share` returns a shared stream, but if you append an operator, you will get a new stream, which is only shared up to the point of the `share`-operator - with `take(n)` it's not too much of a difference, though if there was a switchMap e.g. after the share you'd see a lot of unwanted stuff - so the rule of thumb should be to put any shareing-operator last.